# unity3D with Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am developing  a virtual reality  application for  the  Samsung Gear, I already did the graphic part in unity ,what I want  is when I click on the login button  that I have created with unity,the treatment will be in java, i already have exported my unity project as an android project but I can't find the link between the unity objects that I have created and the generated activity,any help please ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom android plugin for your unity project. You can communicate between java & C# using JNI. For more information, see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)